# Add Custom Parameters with Twitter's Streaming API

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I want to know that if we can associate any custom parameters when tracking keywords using Twitter's public streaming API. What I want to do is to let my application users to search (track) keywords. In that case I would like to know with every tweet that I receive the keyword against which it was searched and streamed. This is important so that I can process the tweet for the user who intended to receive this tweet.

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way to do what you say. But you can always check the text of the tweets you receive. Actually, as explained [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track), you should check *the text attribute of the Tweet, expanded_url and display_url for links and media, text for hashtags, and screen_name for user mentions*

Comment: Yes that looks like the only option but you see that its expensive. For example if I have many keywords stored in database (many records), I will have to match all of my database records from that of a tweet's text.

Comment: Well, if you have it in a database, then it wont be so expensive, you will have to do it only once.... Anyway, you don't have other options. Good luck